# Should I say this forum is a free 'voting discussion' or 'voted discussion' site?

Tags: grammar

I'm building a forum where people can ask questions and get replies. Those questions and replies can get votes but no one can be targeted as best answer.

What's the right way of saying that?

This forum is a free 'voting discussion' or 'voted discussion' site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though they're called "votes", I think a better term to use when describing them and the process behind them would be "ratings".  Stack Exchange, Slashdot, and other sites like them are "forums with member-driven usefulness ratings."

Comment: Why rating instead of votes? Because votes are for electing something specific?

Comment: @janoChen A vote generally intend to select one winner, or sometimes a fixed number of winners. Ratings allow the competitors to be ranked without suggesting that the most voted one should be the/a winner.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little more descriptive with:

> A vote-based discussion site

or even more so:

> A voting-enhanced discussion site